# Practical RSA SecurID authentication with Subversion?

Tags: svn, authentication, rsa

Has anyone setup Subversion with RSA SecurID authentication?  Is there anyway to work around the constant re-prompting for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used SecurID with SVN yet. But it would break the intention of a one-time password system like SecurID if you could authenticate once and be "fine" afterwards.

Comment: I have a VPN that lets me authenticate once with SecurID, and is then fine for several hours.  With SVN, I would be happy with a couple of minutes before it reprompts.  Entering a new SecurId number every ten seconds is not very productive.